# Agregar Getter Vuex a una propiedad data Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

soy nuevo en el desarrollo con Vue, actualmente me encuentro con el problema que no puedo asignar una propiedad computada obtenida por mapGetters a una propiedad data, sin embargo si puedo renderizar el valor de la propiedad computada.

Este es mi codigo:

```
data(){
  return {
  total: 0
 }
}

computed: {
    ...mapGetters('shoppCart', ['cart', 'totalCart'])
}
```

Lo que quiero es asignar el valor de totalCart a total.
He intentado hacerlo en el mounted, sin embargo no funciona.

Comment: Para que quieres asignar lo que tienes en mapGetters a una propiedad data?

Comment: he creado un formulario, necesito procesar información adicional como nombre de cliente, y otros campos, y pues luego mandarlo en una petición post con axios

Comment: Entonces hazlo al momento de crear la llamada con axios, en vez de al montar el componente

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr poner un `alias` a las propiedades a obtener por medio de la función `mapGetters` esta nos ofrece la posibilidad de mandar un objeto como segundo parámetro, dónde la clave del objeto es el alias (nuevo nombre de la variable) y el valor es el nombre original de la propiedad en los getters.

Para obtener el resultado que esperas solo necesitas eliminar total de data (para que no tengas 2 variables con el mismo nombre) y cambiar el segundo parámetro de tu `mapGetters` a algo como lo siguiente:

```javascript
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('shoppCart', {
      cart: 'cart',
      total: 'totalCart',
    }),
  },
};
```

Con la configuración anterior ya podrías acceder a `totalCart` usando `this.total`.

Anexó documentación de vuex dónde se habla de sus sobrecargas: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper